# How to send a form without refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, wordpress

I make a form in Wordpress Template that makes certain calculation and displays the result in a modal Bootstrap.

HTML:

```
 //FORM
<form method="post" id="myForm">   
 <span>Name</span><br><input type="text" name="name" id="name" required>

 <span>Email</span><br>
 <input type="email" name="email"  id="email" required>

 <span>Altura</span><br>
 <input type="number" name="altura" id="altura" required>

<span>Peso</span><br>
<input type="number" name="peso" id="peso" required>
   <br><br>

<button type="submit" id="enviar" onclick="calcularIMC();">Enviar</button>

 //MODAL
<div class="modal fade" id="ajax-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
   <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div id="corpo_modal">
                  <p> ALL FIELDS </p>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
function calcularIMC(){  
var nome = document.getElementById("nome").value; 
var email = document.getElementById("email").value; 
var estilo = document.getElementById("estilo").value; 
var experiencia = document.getElementById("experiencia").value; 
var altura = document.getElementById("altura").value; 
var peso = document.getElementById("peso").value;  
var resultado = 5;

var corpo = document.getElementById("corpo_modal");


var imc = 0;
if(altura >0 && peso >0){
  imc = peso / (altura * altura);
}


 if(estilo == "Surf"){            
         if((imc<=25) && (resultado == 5)){          
          corpo.innerHTML = '<img src="1.png" style="width: 150px; height:150px">';
        }
      else{         
         corpo.innerHTML = '<img src="2.png" style="width: 150px; height:150px">';
          }
     } 


  else if(estilo == "SUP"){  

        if((experiencia >= 3) && (imc <=29)){
          corpo.innerHTML = '<img src="3.png" style="width: 150px; height:150px">';
        } else{
          corpo.innerHTML = '<img src="4.png" style="width: 150px; height:150px">';
        }                       
     }
}
```

The problem is that when I send the form, it updates the page and does not display the modal.
After some research, I found that to solve this problem I will need to use Ajax - jQuery.ajax.

I found this code:

```
$(function() {
  $('form#myForm').on('submit', function(e) {
      $.post('', $(this).serialize(), function (data) {
          // This is executed when the call to mail.php was succesful.
          // 'data' contains the response from the request
      }).error(function() {
          // This is executed when the call to mail.php failed.
      });
      e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

When I create a form in a SEPARATE page without putting in wordpress template, it works. But when I put the code in wordpress template it updates the page after 3 seconds.

I also discovered that I can use a native function `ajax` in `jquery`, the function `$.ajax();` and inside of oneself I use tags like `url`, `type`, `data` and so on. I'm a beginner in Ajax and I'm lost on how to do this.

> Why the function `e.preventDefaul();` not works when I put in wordpress template?? It's possible make it work in wordpress template?

or

> How I can use the `$.ajax()` to solve this problem??

I want send the form without refresh the page!

Comment: Have you included the jquery library?

Comment: Yeah! Definitely yes. Just be posted not find it necessary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look in your javsacript console for errors <kbd>f12</kbd> in your web browser

You'll likely see `undefined variable "$"` or similar error message.

To avoid conflict with other javascript libraries WordPress invokes jQuery  **[noConflict](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/)** by default.

The easiest solution is to wrap your code inside an **[iife](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228281/what-is-the-function-construct-in-javascript)** passing in the `jQuery` object and redefining it as `$`

```
(function($){

   console.log($);
   //your code

})(jQuery)
```

**Further information**

Wordpress has a special url for handling ajax requests and expects an **action** field for which function at the backend should be called:

```
(function($){
    $(function() {
      $('form#myForm').on('submit', function(e) {
          var data = $(this).serialize();
          data += '&action=my_action'
          $.post('<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>', data, function (response) {
            console.log(response)            

         }).error(function() {
             console.log('XHR error')
          });
          e.preventDefault();
      });
    });
})(jQuery)
```

You would then add a handler function into your functions.php file:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_action_callback' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_my_action', 'my_action_callback' );

function my_action_callback() {
    global $wpdb; // this is how you get access to the database

    $whatever = intval( $_POST['whatever'] );

    $whatever += 10;

        echo $whatever;

    wp_die(); // this is required to terminate immediately and return a proper response
}
```

**Further reading**

https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

[How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: Indeed, it was a conflict with JQuery files. Thanks for the very detailed explanation. One question, use the event `e.preventDefault()` to block the page refresh is considered bad practice?

Comment: `e.preventDefault()` is absolutely the correct way to prevent the form from submitting

Comment: Besides e`.preventDefault()` I can also to do this by `$.ajax()`?

Comment: Another possibility is to use a `<button>Submit</button>` instead of `<input type="submit" value="Submit" />` when it is clicked the form will not submit and you can do something like `$('button').click(function(){ $.ajax(...) })` there is no default action to prevent but really, there is nothing wrong with `e.preventDefault();`

Comment: The criterion of knowledge... like this? `$.ajax({ type: "POST", url: "", data: myVariableSerialized, success: function(msg){ alert('Success!'); } });`  Only making this I can stop the refresh of the page? Or I need add more lines of code? If so, what? Do you know tell?

Answer (score 1):

When posting data in wordpress you should handle the request in the **functions.php** file in your wordpress theme.

And you shouldn't use the dollar sign when working with wordpress replace it with **jQuery** which would make the code you posted like this:

```
jQuery(function() {
  jQuery('form#myForm').on('submit', function(e) {
      $.post('', jQuery(this).serialize(), function (data) {
      }).error(function() {
          // This is executed when the call to mail.php failed.
      });
      e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

> Functions.php

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_[action]', 'my_function' );

function my_function() {
    var_dump($_POST);
}
```

The **[action]** placeholder needs to be replaced with the action matched from your ajax call, say for example 'my_action'

```
var data = {
    action: 'my_action',
    form: jQuery(this).serialize()
}

jQuery(function() {
    jQuery('form#myForm').on('submit', function(e) {
        $.post('', data, function(data) {
          }).error(function() {
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Zkk,
You actually don't need to submit anything...
2 quick solutions here:

1. Change your input type to `button`; or
2. Add the following to your javascript tag

:

```
var meuFormulario = document.getElementById("myForm");
meuFormulatio.onsubmit = function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

This will cancel your submit action and only run your javascript function to calculate the `Índice de Massa Corporea (IMC)` you need ;)

Comment: I send the data to Database. So I need to have a `submit`